# Use Flexible Seach For Jasper Report has problems in Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I try to connect Visual JDBC  to Database (MySQL).
Everything looks good.
But when I using Flexible Query or plain SQL syntax have different results.
Reality, The table has a number of records (2 records).
When plain SQL syntax => 2 records => correct.
But Flexible Query => 0 records => false.
Example: Flexible Searchplain vs SQL syntax
[Flexible Search Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RRhm.png)

[Plain SQL Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnOcX.png)

Answer (score 0):

May be orders already deleted. Can you check them in backoffice?
Not: your screenshot and images not match.

Comment: I adding data by manual to test the report.
So, I think that is the cause.

Comment: I added the data manually to test the report.
So, I think that is the cause.
Instead of manually adding,when I add data with backoffice or storefront or impex then the results are OK.
Is it because of cache?

Comment: Yes alright. Hybris has a lot of caching mechanism. Don't insert db directly. Use impex import in hac.